# Why Visual Studio 2012 Tools for unity do not work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use  visual studio 2012 Ultimate and Unity 3.5.1f2.I use Visual Studio 2012 Tools for unity in game programing.When click on the (Visual Studio Tools\open in visual studio) ,show this message : This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual studio
[image]

Visual Studio 2012 Tools for unity installed in vs and imported in unity 
Properly.What is the problem? Please help

Comment: Unity 3.5.1f2 is just too old...

Comment: Which version should I use?(unity & visual studio)

Comment: 4.6.3 or 5.0 should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Libraries\Documents path  is unity projects folders .In this folders is file called  **Assembly-CSharp** if in visual studio click the open project and select this file and then click open : vs can open the files and folders project in the solution.I use this way .
Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the unity plugin for VS as per the documentation on the unity VS website.

The extension you need can be found here ...

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7ab11d2a-f413-4ed6-b3de-ff1d05157714

Comment: It is installed .I reinstall it but it do not work.I think  I should use the newer version of unity.

Comment: for that plugin to work yes you will need unity 5 ... that was my assumption (apologies for that)

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder how I can run VS in Unity 5 without the plugin. Better Download this, before the link gets broken.